# PFQuery using includekey

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have two tables in parse.

- Activity
- Venues

Activity holds two keys: UserID and VenueID. I want to query and retreive the venue details in the Activity table.

I'm trying to do that using this:

```
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:QuoActivityClassName];
    [query whereKey:QuoActivityFavoritesUserID equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query includeKey:QuoActivityVenueID];

    if (self.objects.count == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    return query;
```

This retrieves the object but how do I grab the specific fields in the venues table like the name, address, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Venue from returned object from PFQuery as:

```
Venue * venue = object[QuoActivityVenueID];
```

You can also do:

```
NSString * venueName = object[QuoActivityVenueID][Some_Name_Id];
NSString * venueAddress = object[QuoActivityVenueID][Some_Address_Id];
```